# Ожидание события c#

Tags: c#, .net

Делаю свою консоль на c# и winforms, столкнулся с проблемой : для реализации методов Read и ReadLine надо подождать, пока пользователь введет данные(если он еще не сделал этого)

```
public string ReadLine()
{
    //wait for "Enter"

    return "output";
}

public string Read()
{
   //wait for "Enter"

   return "output";
}

private void Console_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

   //paint console

}
```

, причем во время ожидания нажатия клавиши enter консоль должна перерисовываться, форма, код которой вызывает метод Read или ReadLine тоже не должна виснуть. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вызывайте ReadLine из другого потока. По-другому никак

Comment: Но мне же надо ждать, пока закончится ввод, а если создать поток, то выполнение кода в основном потоке продолжится

Comment: Ну так будет другой поток будет ждать. Вы не можете заставить UI поток ждать, и при этом еще отрисовывать форму. Можно пойти другим путем и сделать ваши методы `async`. Но в таком случае так же поток не будет ждать

Comment: Вы, наверное, неверно меня поняли, мне надо, чтобы в определенный момент выполнение кода в основном потоке остановилось(но тем не менее события обрабатывались), а потом, когда сработало событие нажатия на кнопку enter, возобновилось с того же места

Comment: Покажите лучше, как вы хотите использовать эти методы. Откуда они будут вызываться?

Comment: ну, если в кратце, я делаю что-то типа scratch или google blockly, и там может вызываться консоль для пользовательского ввода. У формы, которая представляет собой консоль, в коде содержатся методы read и readline, которые вызываются из основной формы во время выполнения, и выполнение программы должно приостанавливаться, пока пользователь не введет данные(но формы не должны зависать)